# Channel Images: Migrating to CloudFiles

Tags: channel-images, migration, devdemon, cloudfiles

I have a client that needs to migrate to CloudFiles (currently hosting their assets on their own server). DevDemon indicated that they have a migration-script for current entries, but they are nowhere to be found (tried contacting them over e-mail and Google+), does anyone have a solution for this? They have over 2000 entries with Channel Images, so manual migration would be a PITA.

Thanks!

- Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration script has been written and already tested by a couple of people. Get in touch so we can send you the updated build.